# Active Sheet copy with Range

Tags: vba, excel

Today I need to copy my activesheet with range, not all the page.

I have this code for the moment:

```
Sub Save1()
 Dim NomFichier, Nom
 Nom = Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) & "_" & Hour(Time) & "-" & Minute(Time) & "-" & Second(Time)

ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Illyana\Documents\Dropbox\Personnel\Freddy\Audit réalisé\Chambre 100\" & "Chambre_" & ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & Nom

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\Illyana\Documents\Dropbox\Personnel\Freddy\Audit réalisé\Chambre 100\PDF\" & "Chambre_" & ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & Nom, Quality:= _
xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
Sub Reinitialiser()
    [D4:J53].ClearContents
End Sub
```

But when I change this line: `ActiveSheet.Copy` by that: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J72").Copy` the copy works, but a workbook is created with all the sheets.

What can I do for save just the activesheet with the good range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `Range.Copy` Method you will need to specify the destination Range to copy the data to. I've updated the code below with comments to show how to copy the Range to a new worksheet in a new workbook. You will need to change "WorksheetName" to the name of the worksheet containing your data:

```
Sub Save1()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsDest As Excel.Worksheet
Dim NomFichier, Nom
Nom = Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) & "_" & Hour(Time) & "-" & Minute(Time) & "-" & Second(Time)

' Reference the Worksheet containing the data to be copied
' Change "WorksheetName" to the name of the Worksheet to copy from
Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WorksheetName")

' Create a new Workbook with one Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

' Set a reference to the Worksheet in the new Workbook
Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets(1)

' Copy the data to the new Worksheet, paste at Cell "A1"
wsSource.Range("A1:J72").Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Illyana\Documents\Dropbox\Personnel\Freddy\Audit réalisé\Chambre 100\" & "Chambre_" & wsSource.Name & "_" & Nom

wsDest.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                        Filename:="C:\Users\Illyana\Documents\Dropbox\Personnel\Freddy\Audit réalisé\Chambre 100\PDF\" & "Chambre_" & wsSource.Name & "_" & Nom, Quality:= _
                        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                        From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok it's work but I have a problem with the layout is not the same. The copy don't save the width of each cell and the new sheet don't take the same name that the original

Answer (score 1):

The following line of your code:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                Filename:="C:\Users\Illyana\Documents\Dropbox\Personnel\Freddy\Audit réalisé\Chambre 100\PDF\" & "Chambre_" & ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & Nom, _
                                Quality:= xlQualityStandard, _
                                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                From:=1, To:=1, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

will export `ActiveSheet` as a PDF file.

To export **just** `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J72")` you should say:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J72").ExportAsFixedFormat _
                                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                Filename:="C:\Users\Illyana\Documents\Dropbox\Personnel\Freddy\Audit réalisé\Chambre 100\PDF\" & "Chambre_" & ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & Nom, _
                                Quality:= xlQualityStandard, _
                                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                From:=1, To:=1, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Your lines of code saying

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Illyana\Documents\Dropbox\Personnel\Freddy\Audit réalisé\Chambre 100\" & "Chambre_" & ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & Nom
```

are not needed in order to perform the Export.  (The SaveAs may be needed for other reasons, e.g. because you want to save a copy of the entire workbook in one directory and the PDF version in the sub-directory.  The Copy definitely isn't needed.)

Comment: I export the file in pdf for security but I want to export also the sheet, that why I use the PDF export in a second time

Comment: @ThéoMercier-balaz - Sounds a good reason - so get rid of the `Copy`, but keep the `SaveAs`.

Comment: I have a problem that when I export the sheet, the layout is not the same..

Comment: @ThéoMercier-balaz - When you say `export the sheet` do you mean saving the workbook, or exporting the range?

Comment: Export the sheet in new Workbook with one sheet, the one who is export, so the range. The layout is just horrible !

Comment: @ThéoMercier-balaz - Are you trying to comment on my answer, or on the answer by Socii.  My answer didn't attempt to create a new workbook (other than the SaveAs).

Comment: OH ! I thought that . Sorry :/ ^^